# Addclass to another on radio select

Tags: jquery

I have code:

```
<ul id="block1">
    <li class="current"><a href='#block1-1'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#block1-2'>2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='block1-1' class='question-content'>Question 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q1-answer" id="block1-q1-a" value="a">A. answer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q1-answer" id="block1-q1-b" value="b">B. answer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q1-answer" id="block1-q1-c" value="c">C. answer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q1-answer" id="block1-q1-d" value="d">D. answer<br>
</div>
<div id='block1-2' class='question-content'>Salov 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q2-answer" id="block1-q2-a" value="a">A. answer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q2-answer" id="block1-q2-b" value="b">B. answer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q2-answer" id="block1-q2-c" value="c">C. answer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="block1-q2-answer" id="block1-q2-d" value="d">D. answer<br>
</div>
```

What I want is: when user select radio button i must addclass to question number

Here is my jquery:

```
$(".question-content").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("choosen");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("choosen");
});
```

P.S. sorry i forgot to post jquery

Comment: Have you tried jQuery code?

Comment: @ShaunakD I bet you were like this when you started learning jQuery, commenting like this is not nice :(

Comment: @DanielCheung, no intention to blame someone. I was asking OP about his code, if any, to put it in the question instead of just HTML. And you took it in the wrong way :/

Comment: @ShaunakD You don't understand, or you may have forgotten. You wouldn't know any code when you *just* started learning. Without the process of asking and answering, you won't even be able to search on Google with the special terms, like **"click event" or "listener" or even "jquery API"**

Comment: May I know where is the `<div>` to which you need to add class `choosen`? Add it to your html. And your click event should be on `input` as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function () {
    $('a[href=#'+$(this).parent().attr('id')+']').addClass('chosen');
});
```

please see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0v2d2akq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to understand code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".question-content input").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass("my-class");
    })
})
```

Basically, the code runs after the document is loaded. It checks for when an input of `.question-content` is clicked, it runs `$(this).parent().addClass("my-class");`. Which means find its parent, which is one of the `question-content`, and add the class `my-class` to it.

Feel free to ask for more explanation. ;)

Comment: i have tried this but this is not as i want becuse Question number is located in another div not parent div

Comment: @Newmaster then I don't understand what you say, you mean you haven't posted all relevant code?